# How to get the most out of laptop battery life of a Windows PC?

Tags: laptop, battery-life, performance

I'm a big fan of portability and battery life. I want to take the most out of a single recharge. Any tips to accomplish that?

Things on top of my mind:

- Voltage reduction (with RMClock, any better software?)
- Reduce brightness
- Turning off devices (any software to do that automatically?)

Answer (score 5):

Which laptop? Most laptops come with software which does a discharge-recharge cycle, that can increase battery performance. Check the website of the laptop manufacturer.

Other things :

- Disable wireless
- Do not use the CD/DVD Drive

These settings can be automatically set using Windows power manager.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Windows Vista, the [Vista Battery Saver](http://www.codeplex.com/vistabattery) program can help disable OS features that suck up processing energy that is less than ideal for a computer operating on a limited energy bar.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the biggest battery saver I've when trying to conserve power is to reduce brightness.

In addition - adjust your power settings.