# How can I maximize my battery global lifetime?

Tags: laptop, battery-life

My laptop is used as a desktop computer, and is always plugged-in.

I heard that battery should be fully discharged/recharged at least once a month.
Is that true?

Are there other efficient ways to improve my battery global lifetime?

---

I'm aware of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/421/how-to-get-the-most-out-of-laptop-battery-life-of-a-windows-pc) which focuses on getting the most of a single charge, which is not what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends almost entirely on the checmical composition of the battery you are using.  For example a NimH battery has different lifetime and charge/disachage recommendations then a Li-Ion or older NiCad batteries.

Forget what make/model computer you have (ie Apple, PC etc), what matters is what sort of battery you have.

So, first find out your battery type, then check out [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rechargeable_battery) for a more information.

Answer (score 2):

That Apple link only recommends discharging the battery if you're not using the laptop very often.

From everything I've read, heat is the biggest enemy of laptop batteries.  The ideal situation is to remove the battery when its charged and the laptop is plugged in, but I'm far too lazy to do that :).

You can find out everything you ever wanted to know about batteries from Dan's Data [here](http://www.dansdata.com/gz011.htm) and [here](http://www.dansdata.com/gz042.htm).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html) are the recommendations for maximising battery life in Apple notebooks.

In summary, they recommend that it is not plugged in at all times and that the battery should be fully discharged/charged once per month.